# Incomplete gamma function as a sum

Tags: summation, gamma-function

The incomplete gamma function is well known as: $\Gamma(n,x) = \int_x^{+\infty} t^{n-1} e^{-t} dt$. This function for positive values of its first argument $n>1$ has a "sum" representation as:
$$
\Gamma(n,x) = (n-1)! e^{-x} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{x^k}{k!}
$$
with $(.)!$ being the factorial function and is valid for *any value of $x$*.

My question is : is there a representation as a "sum" for negative values of $n$ ? I tried to find out on the Internet but no way. A friend helped me with his own try and found out this one:
$$
\Gamma(n,x) = \frac{x^n}{(-n)!} e^{-x} \sum_{k=0}^{-n+1} \frac{x^{k-1}}{(-n+k)!}
$$
but I tried it on Mathematica and it does not work.

Any help ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a sum formula for negative $n$ but it contains the exponential integral $E_1(x)$ given in http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.4#E15: 
$$\Gamma(-n,x) = \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\left( E_1(x) - e^{-x} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^k k!}{x^{k+1}}\right)$$

Comment: Simply excellent ! Thank you !

Comment: @gammatester What about if n starts from 0, (i.e. 0, -1, -2, ....).

Comment: @barznjy: There is nothing special about the case $n=0,\;$  the sum is just empty:
$\Gamma(0,x) = E_1(x).\;$ But it is also listed separately in http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.4.E4

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fundamental property $$\sum_{k=0}^n a_k=a_n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k$$ to define the sum for negative $n$. In particular, setting $n=0$ you conclude that $$\sum_{k=0}^{-1} a_k=0.$$ Next, insert $n=-1$ in the formula to get $$\sum_{k=0}^{-2}a_k=-a_{-1},$$ and so forth. Proceed by induction.

Comment: Granted, the resulting definition looks somewhat odd. It might have looked better had $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k$ been defined to *exclude* the final term $a_n$.

Comment: I am just now trying integration by parts. Definying $\Gamma(-n,x) = I_{n+1}$ for $n>0$, I get:
$$
I_{n+1} = \frac{e^{-x}}{n x^n} - \frac{1}{n} I_{n},
$$
and I am just trying to find a good form to represent the final result.